# SAP Design Time Repository Branching like Git or SVN

Tags: version-control, netweaver

In SAP NetWeaver Design Time Repository is there an equivalent to SVN or Git style branching? I would like to be able to branch a SC for some development work on particular features while maintaining a main development trunk. Also it would be useful to be able to have tagging of stable releases.

I've been working with a tool to migrate our code from NetWeaver Developer Studio to SVN, but if we could make it work properly in DTR that would be better. So far though I haven't been able to find any equivalent function.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what do you mean under branching. If we speak about simple [SVN-style branching](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.whatis.html) then SAP concept of [development track](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_NWce72/helpdata/en/49/2fe24eb7476b1fe10000000a42189d/frameset.htm) can fit into your needs:

[image]

As it stated by the SAP

> When a development project is started, the landscape administrator
>   initially uses the CMS to create a new track.
>  A track is a **separate
>   production line** for a certain release of an SC.

In other words track works like a simple branch, so you can try following scenario:

1. Create several different tracks (or [copy existing track](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/78/baf9188e054213a5a38cc81e67037c/content.htm?frameset=/en/07/499a1c97fc4440bd6312d93d4010e9/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/43/05e450d1cd6e95e10000000a11466f/plain.htm&node_id=1958) to a new one)
2. Do development in different tracks independently.
3. In the end merge changes from two tracks or just delete the unnecessary ones. Until  changes are activated and imported into QA the actual state of PROD **will not be modified**.

**UPDATE:** [following link](https://blogs.sap.com/2005/09/21/best-practicesjdi-branching-patterns-use-cases/) describes several branching patterns in NWDI and can be helpful.